# State inside loop that is running inside async function doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

I have two functions one function to fetch data using API inside the loop and a second function that changes a state cancel from false to true. But that state doesn't update inside that loop hence I cannot stop the API call.

Below is the template code

```js
const [cancel, setCancel] = useState(false);
const cancelFtn = ()=>{
setCancel(true)
}
```

```js
const fetchData = async ()=>{
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          const res = await fetch(putObjectSignedUrl, {
          method: "PUT",
          body: files[i],
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });
 if (res) {
//cancel state doesn't change here if in between iteration of loop I have called cancelFtn function on click of some button
          if (!cancel) {
            await fetchInvoiceData(key);
          } else {
            console.log("Cancelled");
          }
   }
}
```

I want an updated state inside the loop. I have tried to use effect too but it also didn't work

Comment: The issue seems to be with the calling of the `cancelFtn`  function the js is busy executing the for loop and will do other things after the loop ends.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think that with this case it is better to use a ref for your cancel